# How to parse inner array elements of an inner element json

Tags: ios, json, swift3

[this is my JSON response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MD1J.png)

I want to parse this JSON

**Home.swift**

```
  self.resultFromJsonGlobal = (dict?["restaurants"]as?[[String : AnyObject]])!

           // let annotionsArray: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
            for resultFromJson in self.resultFromJsonGlobal

            {
                let socialType = resultFromJson["social_type"]as? String
                let role = resultFromJson["role_code"]as? String
                let Price = resultFromJson["price"]as? Strin
                let rate = resultFromJson["ratings"]as? String
                let ImageUrl = resultFromJson["image"]as? String
                let Discriptions = resultFromJson["descriptions"]as? String
            }
```

I am getting the value of socialType,role,rate,ImageUrl.But i am not getting the value of price and discriptions.

Comment: first you have to get items array and then get you description and price from this array.

Comment: @BHAVIKPANCHAL any sample code is available??

Comment: can you try like this let Items = resultFromJson["items"]as? NSArray

for i in 0 ..< Items.count
{

    let dic = data.object(at: i) as! NSDictionary
    let price = dic.object(forKey: "price") as! String
    let Discriptions = dic.object(forKey: "descriptions") as! String
    
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this piece of code.

```
  self.resultFromJsonGlobal = (dict?["restaurants"]as?[[String : AnyObject]])!

    // let annotionsArray: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    for resultFromJson in self.resultFromJsonGlobal            
    {
        let socialType = resultFromJson["social_type"] as? String
        let role = resultFromJson["role_code"] as? String
        let rate = resultFromJson["ratings"] as? String
        let ImageUrl = resultFromJson["image"] as? String

        if let items =  resultFromJson["items"] as? [Any]
        {
            for item in items
            {
                let dic = item as! [String:Any]
                let Price = dic["price"] as? String
                let Discriptions = dic["descriptions"] as? String
            }
        }
    }
```